# Tweak Google Scholar recommended articles

Tags: google-scholar

I signed up to receive a "Recommended articles" email from Google Scholar, which arrives every few days. The recommended papers usually address the same substantive area as my research but very rarely come from disciplines/journals relevant to my field. As such the recommendations are, sadly, pretty useless. Is there a way to narrow the recommended articles to certain disciplines, or at least specific journals and working paper depositories?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=create_alert_options&alert_params=hl%3Den&hl=en

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Not sure what you're suggesting. I could create an alert w boolean criterion to cover every word related to research I care about and every journal I care about: word1|word2|word3....&journal1|journal2|journal3...    This does not seem like a good solution

Comment: Why are there close votes? This is a specific question that, in theory, has an answer and it would be of use to many academics. I've googled it and there's no obvious answer

Comment: I consider "How do I used Google Scholar?" and similar questions about web applications to be off topic.  Google invariably fails to provide an answer to obvious questions about Scholar.

Comment: Keeping up with publications is a core part of my job as a prof, so I consider discussions about how to do that, including via tech, to fall under the broad umbrella of academic career discussion

Comment: A question like that would be on topic, but your question is not like that. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107041/how-to-keep-up-with-new-publications-and-conferences-rss-feed

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/efficient-method-to-receive-alerts-for-new-publications?rq=1

Comment: My question is indeed about that, how to better use a specific tool for keeping up with academic pubs. A Boolean alert would be onerous to write, but if there is no way to narrow the recommended articles, then the answer to the question may simply be, “No, unfortunately there’s no way to narrow recommended articles. A complex Boolean alert is the best way.”